# Reading Browser favorites (links) from an Adobe AIR application

Tags: android, apache-flex, air, favorites

Is it possible to get read access to favorited sites (that have been set using Android's native browser) from within an AIR-application? I could not find an API for this. Furthermore, I didn't find anything about browsing android's filesystem.  It seems something like a favorites folder does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can access it through the Android Content Provider api. Specifically, it's right here in the Android API: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Browser.html#BOOKMARKS_URI here is the Content Provider developer guide: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html

This tutorial shows how to actually work with bookmarks specifically: http://mobileorchard.com/android-app-development-android-content-providers/

To access this from AIR I thinkyou'll need to write a NativeExtension. Here are some examples: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air.html but maybe you can access that URI directly from AIR with a service or something? I don't do much native android so I don't know for sure.

Comment: I don't think native extensions are supported until 4.6 gets officially released.

Comment: Native extensions are supported now by the AIR 3 SDK. The Flash Builder publishing tools don't support them fully yet, but you can drop to the command line or an Ant script.

Comment: Thank you everybody - I'll take a look into NativeExtensions!